# RxJS delay at least X milliseconds

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement the following behavior in RxJS:

1. Fire an event
2. Call an http API
3. When the API returns, either:

   1. Wait until at least X milliseconds have passed since firing the event
   2. Return immediately if X milliseconds have already passed since firing the event

This would is very useful for UX, because even if the call takes 1ms, I'd like to show a loading icon for at least 100ms.

I haven't found any way to implement this either with `delay`, `throttle`, `debounce` or its variations.

```
this.eventThatFires
    .switchMap(data => {
        let startTime = Date.now();
        return this.callHttpService(data)
            .delay(new Date(startTime + 1000));
    })
```

I assumed something like this worked, but using an absolute date seems to do a time difference with the current time, and not schedule the delay for that absolute time.

---

EDIT:

It seems there's no built-in operator that works as what I describe. I just created it because I'll be using it a lot throughout my application:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

function delayAtLeast<T>(this: Observable<T>, delay: number): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(
        Observable.timer(delay),
        this)
    .map(([_, i]) => i);
}

Observable.prototype.delayAtLeast = delayAtLeast;

declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        delayAtLeast: typeof delayAtLeast;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively `delay` by date is the same as `delay` by number, the only difference is that delay duration is computed as difference of specified date and current time.

You can use `delayWhen` operator to compute delay when value is emitted:

```
this.eventThatFires
    .switchMap(data => {
        let startTime = Date.now();
        return this.callHttpService(data)
            .delayWhen(() => Rx.Observable.timer(500 + startTime - Date.now()))
    })
```

Comment: I'm going to wrap this in my own method for now, but thanks for the confirmation that `delay` doesn't work with absolute times. And also for providing an alternative!

Comment: The biggest pitfall for me was the execution time difference between `delay` and `delayWhen`. When piped, `delay` is executed immediately whereas `delayWhen` executes after receiving the response, which makes the remaining time calculation different. In general the solution proposed by Brandon is more understandable.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with your combineLatest solution?

You can also use `zip`:

```
this.eventThatFires
    .switchMap(data => Observable.zip(
        this.profileService.updateInfo(profileInfo)),
        Observable.timer(500),
        x => x));
```

Comment: My feeling was that a `delay` operator with an absolute `datetime` would work as I expected, and I spent some good time investigating that and other options since it looked like there could be a built-in implementation. Now I'm probably going to add my own `delayAtLeast` operator, since I plan to use it a lot. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom rxjs operator based off of Martin's final solution.

```
import { combineLatest, Observable, OperatorFunction, timer } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export function delayAtLeast<T>(delay: number): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return function(source$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return combineLatest([timer(delay), source$]).pipe(map(x => x[1]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Bogdan Savluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3727009/bogdan-savluk) answer. Delay functionality decoupled:

```
let effectiveDelay=(delay)=>{
    let effectiveTimer = (now=>delay=>timer(delay+now - Date.now() )) (Date.now())
    return delayWhen(()=>effectiveTimer(delay));
}


this.eventThatFires
    .switchMap(data => this.callHttpService(data)
                .pipe(effectiveDelay(500)))
```

Case of http request (poll at least every x seconds)

```
of({}).pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
        return ajax({url:"https://httpbin.org/delay/2", crossDomain:true})
              .pipe(effectiveDelay(1000), map(ax=>ax.response) )
    }), tap(display), repeat())
  .subscribe()
```

See: [online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-example-gyjyys?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
forkJoin([ this.eventThatFires, timer(500) ]).pipe(
  map(([ result ]) => result)
)
```

`forkJoin` waits until both `this.eventThatFires` and `timer(500)` trigger. It returns an array, being only the first element of it what we need, so we use the `map` to get it.

Comment: I don't think `forkJoin` emits when both of the inputs **trigger**, as much as when they both **complete**.  See https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r5kjji?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts